# powershell script to add triggers to azure devops build pipelines

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure Devops build pipeline, I want to add triggers automatically using powershell script via Azure DevOps API's. I have at least 10 pipelines that need to be updated when there is a new release. I looked around in MS documentation but couldn't find anything promising. Is there anyway to achieve this without opening all the definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to achieve this without opening all the definitions.

Yes. You can use the Rest API: [Definition-Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to add the triggers to Pipeline.

Here is the PowerShell script example:

If the pipeline has no existing pipeline trigger, you can use the following sample to add triggers.

```
$token = "PAT"


$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$definitionids= 1,2,3,4,5

foreach($definitionid in $definitionids)
{

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{Project}/_apis/build/definitions/$($definitionid)?api-version=7.0"
echo $url

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method GET -ContentType application/json

$triggervalue =@"
[
        {
            "branchFilters": [
                "+refs/heads/master"
            ],
            "pathFilters": [],
            "batchChanges": false,
            "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch": 1,
            "pollingInterval": 0,
            "triggerType": "continuousIntegration"
        }
    ]
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json



$response | add-member -Name "triggers" -value @($triggervalue) -MemberType NoteProperty


$newrevision = $response.revision


$response.revision = $newrevision

echo $response.revision

$json = @($response) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $json -ContentType application/json 
}
```

If the Pipeline has existing triggers, you can use the following sample to update the trigger:

```
$token = "PAT"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$definitionids= 1,2,3,4,5

foreach($definitionid in $definitionids)
{

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{Project}/_apis/build/definitions/$($definitionid)?api-version=7.0"
echo $url

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method GET -ContentType application/json

echo $response.triggers[0].branchFilters[0]

$response.triggers[0].branchFilters[0] = "+refs/heads/test"

$newrevision = $response.revision


$response.revision = $newrevision

echo $response.revision

$json = @($response) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $json -ContentType application/json 
}
```

**Note:** we can use the Rest API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to get the current trigger information or trigger field format in request body.